# How to dump the machine instructions used by a Perl program

Tags: perl

Two related questions

1. After I run a program how can I see what machine code got executed?
2. Moreover does perl execution convert the whole pl and its modules to machine code or just the part it executes?

Comment: What are you trying to do where you think you need to know this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl is an [interpreted language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)).  A more detailed look at how Perl works shows that perl has some features of compilers, some of interpreters.  For more info see the [introduction to perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#DESCRIPTION) and the [compiler section of perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Compiled-code).

Perl is compiled into a set of opcodes that are executed by a virtual machine that is part of the perl binary.  You can see these opcodes by using a tool like [B::Concise](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Concise.html).

If you want to see actual processor specific instructions, you are going to have to do some serious black magic.  You could run perl on a special virtual machine that is configured to record all instructions executed by a given executable.

Another possible approach is to use [B::C](http://search.cpan.org/dist/B-C/lib/B/C.pm) to create a compiled C version of your Perl script.  You can then examine the native compiled code.

Comment: [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/strace) / [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/dtrace) are helpful, too. They work on the system call level.

Comment: Faster (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Faster) might be interesting to look at as well (since it on the fly converts a Perl program into an XS one, it is probably possible to hack it to show how it is doing it)